# Must I Show these Functions are Homomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I am trying to prove the snake lemma. I want to show that the sequence of kernels form an exact sequence. Must I show that the functions that map one kernel to the other are R-module homomorphisms?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The functions that map one kernel already come from existing homomorphisms, you don't have to explicitly show it

Comment: @Osama Ghani Okay. Thanks.